# Calculate a CDF for event X given a function specifying the probability of event X happening per unit time

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I know that the probability of event X occurring is constant over time:

$$P(X) = k$$

For a given amount of time, I would like to calculate the probability that event X first occurs within this time.

In the case of discrete time slots, I can calculate the probability of the first occurrence of event X happening at time slot n:

$$k * (1-k)^{n-1}$$

So that the probability of event having happened for the first time within the first n time slots is given by:

$$\sum_{t=1}^{n} k * (1-k)^{n-1}$$

This is as far as my intuition goes.

I would like to find out how to calculate the CDF of event X happening for the first time on a **continuous** time scale.

I know I would need to integrate instead of summing over things, but I'm not exactly sure how to go about this.

Without having a formal training in maths, I'm afraid this might be a relatively simple question, so if you don't feel like giving me the solution I would appreciate it if you could forward me to a resource where I could learn how to do this specifically.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: to transition from discrete to continuous time, simply put, you need to take a limit $n \rightarrow \infty$ and at the same time $t \rightarrow 0$ but so that together $nt = T$ remains fixed ($T$ is the time variable for your cdf). You should check your expressions for the discrete case though, I don't think they are quite right.

Comment: You're right! I corrected the equations now. I just left home right now but I'll think about what you wrote and get back with a reply. Thanks a lot for the hint!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The description of the problem is not exactly clear. However, I suppose
you mean that events occur at a constant rate $\lambda$ over time, and
that you want the distribution of the waiting time $X$ for the first occurrence.

Then $X \sim \mathsf{Exp}(\lambda).$ You can read some details about
the exponential distribution in the relevant Wikipedia article.
In particular, the density function (PDF) of $X$ is $f_X(t) = \lambda e^{-\lambda t},$ for $t > 0,$ and $E(X) = 1/\lambda.$

The cumulative distribution
function of $X$ is
$$F(X \le t) = F_X(t) = \int_0^t f_X(t)\,dt = 1 - e^{-\lambda t},$$
for $t > 0.$

For example, if the average waiting time is $E(X) = 2$ hours, then $\lambda = 1/2$ and the probability you will have to wait more than 3 hours until
the event occurs is 
$$P(X > 3) = 1 - P(X \le 3) = e^{-3/2} =  0.22313.$$

In the figure below, the area representing $P(X > 3)$ is beneath the
curve to the right of the broken red line.

[image]

---

**Addendum:** *Derivation of exponential distribution from Poisson distribution.*

Let $\lambda$ be the rate per unit time of Poisson events. Then the
number $Y_t$ of events in the interval $(0, t]$ has $Y_t \sim \mathsf{Pois}(\lambda t).$ Also let $X$ be the waiting time, starting at time $t = 0,$
until the first Poisson event occurs. Then the events $\{Y_t = 0\}$
and $\{X > t\}$ are the same. Thus the CDF of $X$ is

$$F_X(t) = P(X \le t) = 1 - P(X > t) = 1 - P(Y_t = 0) = 1 - e^{-\lambda t},$$
for $t > 0.$

By differentiation, the PDF of $X$ is 
$$f_X(t) = dF_X(t)/dt = \lambda e^{-\lambda t},$$
for $ t > 0.$ Using integration by parts, one can show that 
$E(X) = \int_0^\infty tf_X(t)\,dt = 1/\lambda,$ and also $SD(X) = 1/\lambda.$

Comment: Thanks a lot Bruce. I guess my question was more related to how to derive the PDF itself. I already knew the PDF in this particular case (it is super related to the poisson equations), but I would like to learn how to derive this in case I start of with a different equation.

Comment: For example, if the probability of event X occurring over time was not kept at a constant k, but increased with time (P(X) was not always k, but kt, for example), how could I derive this? I am guessing this has to do with the limits Nick has mentioned in his reply above, but I need to read about that to fully understand his hints.

Comment: OK. I'll address that briefly at the end. I hope that's what you were looking for.

Comment: Thanks again. You really helped me understand how to go from $Pois(kt)$ to $1 - e^{-kt}$ so I'll mark this question as answered.

I have also read the derivation of the Poisson equation so I understand how to go from my initial statement to Pois(kt). 

However, I am now left wondering how to derive the distributions for events whose probability of first occurrence changes with time (e.g. a constant increase in probability with time such that P(first occurrence) is not k but kt). But that might be something I should ask in a separate question. Thanks again and have a good evening!

Comment: More generally than exponential, you may want to consider 'failure rate' or 'hazard rate' $h(t) = f(t)/[1-F(t)]$ which can be used to describe reliability models. For exponential $h(t) = \lambda$ is const. For Weibull, $h(t)$ can be increasing or decreasing with time. A reliability model can be characterized by $h(t), f(t), F(t),$ or $R(t) = 1-F(t),$ with some use of diff. eq. to get from one to another. [_This_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Failure_rate#hazard_function) Wikipedia article may be a good place to start.